# if statement execute always , controlling issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, c#-4.0, if-statement

I am stuck by an annoying problem in my code. I am using DATE FROM----DATE TO boxes to select range of date to display employees between that date ranges in WEBGRID but problem is that in first display it appears exactly according to that date ranges but when i do pagination (clicking page 2, 3 , 4....) then it picks all employees record for every date because i have set IF condition like that if DatFrom and TO are empty then pick all results

so how to implement it correctly ?

```
 public ActionResult ShowCalTextBox(String DateFrom, String DateTo) 
        {

            if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo == "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateFrom = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for"+" "+ DateFrom ;
                return View(EmpRec_DateFrom);

            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo != "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateTo = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records for" + " " + DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_DateTo);
            }
            else if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo != "") 
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_ByDate = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, DateTo).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "Records from" + " " + DateFrom +" "+"to"+" "+DateTo;
                return View(EmpRec_ByDate);
            }
            else if (DateFrom == "" && DateTo == "")
            {
                IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_Default = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(null, null).ToList();
                ViewBag.Dates = "No date selection";
                return View(EmpRec_Default);
            }

            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult About()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

actually i think problem is here

```
public ActionResult ShowCalTextBox(String DateFrom, String DateTo) 
            {

                if (DateFrom != "" && DateTo == "") 
                {
                    IEnumerable<GetEmpRec_DateResult> EmpRec_DateFrom = DataContext.GetEmpRec_Date(DateFrom, null).ToList();
                    ViewBag.Dates = "Records for"+" "+ DateFrom ;
                    return View(EmpRec_DateFrom);

                }
```

VIEW:

```
@using EmployeeAttendance_app.Models
<div>
@using (Html.BeginForm("ShowCalTextBox", "Home", FormMethod.Post)) 
{
  <label id="lblFrom">From</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxFrom" name="DateFrom" />
  <label id="lblTo">To</label>
  <input type="text" id="TxtBoxTo" name="DateTo"  />
  <br />
  <br />
  <button type="submit" id="btnSubmitDate" name="btnSubmit">Submit</button>  
}
</div>

<div>
 <h4>@ViewBag.Dates</h4>
 <br />
 @{

     var grid = new WebGrid(ViewData.Model, rowsPerPage: 20, canPage: false);

  }

 <div id="AllEmpGrid_ByDate">
   @grid.GetHtml(columns: grid.Columns(
                                        grid.Column("EmplID", "Employee ID"),
                                        grid.Column("EmplName","Employee Name"),
                                        grid.Column("ShiftID", "Shift ID"),
                                        grid.Column("DateVisited", "Date of Visit"),
                                        grid.Column("InTime", "In Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TimeOut", "Time Out"),
                                        grid.Column("OverTime", "Over Time"),
                                        grid.Column("TotalWorkingTime", "Total Working Time")    
                                      ))
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Are you doing a post after setting the date? If yes then please paste your view code also.

Comment: Please check that on changing the page number, is it doing a post to the ShowCalTextBox action? If yes, check what values are coming for the dates.

Comment: ShowCalTextBox remains same but only page=2. page=3 are appended and DateFrom, DateTo becomes "" empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is that the page grid makes a get request instead of post. Possibly you can get hold of it by including the following javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
        $('th a, tfoot a').click(function () {
            $('form').attr('action', $(this).attr('href')).submit();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: man i solved it just i changed form method from POST to GET, why it worked >?

Comment: Because the WebGrid on page changing fires a GET request to get the data.

Comment: so what's a big deal ? Question is why it worked with GEt but not with Post

Comment: Did you put a HTTPPost attribute over the action?

Comment: No, why ? any special usage ?

Comment: When you write in your form "FormMethod.Post". Then the action with "HTTPPost" attribute is searched for. If you do not specify anything by default it is "HTTPGet".

Comment: i am getting confused bro, see i didn't mention GET in method, so it was not working, but when i mentioned GET then it started working, if by default it was GET then why it wasn't working before i mentioned GET explicitly

Comment: The HTTPGet & HTTPPost attributes are put over the action method. What you were specifying is FormMethod in the BeginForm helper method. The FormMethod specifies how the form would be submitted on submit button click. Now what possibly was happening is, that the page changing was initiating a submit button click. i.e. it was sending the form and the form was sent using the Post method, while your action method was set to HTTPGet(by default), you could have put the HTTPPost on action method and it would have worked. Or the other way round what you did.